# Google Cloud Data Fusion Multiple Data Base Plugin and Loading the file into GCS Multi File Plugin In Parquet Format Giving Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to extract data from MySQL to GCS using cloud data fusion in parquet format, however when running the pipeline/validating the pipeline I am getting error

```
Error encountered while configuring the stage: 'Unable to create config for validatingOutputFormat parquet Required property 'schema' is missing.'
```

which is asking for schema however It is not the case with other format and it is extracting the data smoothly. Since it is a multi file I am unsure which schema I need to define.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Output schema cant be empty, you need to specify the schema that will come out from the source. Can you set it accordingly and try again? Please follow this doc for more instructions https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/745963651/MySQL+Batch+Source

Comment: I'm utilizing a plugin that draws data from multiple database tables as input and outputs it as multiple files in Google Cloud Storage (GCS). Since I'm employing various queries to retrieve data, I'm uncertain about which schema to define. Although I've enabled "Allow flexible schemas" in the output, it's not functioning as expected. Disabling it is causing issues in the pipeline.

Comment: * can you share the name of the plugin? * Each parquet file will has its own schema based on its source?

Comment: Source: Multiple Table Plugins
Sink: GCS Multi File

But It is not possible to provide 100 files schema into the output. It's not good for developer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my answer based on the comments and the details we had above;

- Allow flexible schemas in Output [param works only with](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/464945223/Google+Cloud+Storage+Multi+File+Sink#:%7E:text=Optional.%20When%20enabled%2C%20this%20sink%20will%20write%20out%20records%20with%20arbitrary%20schemas.%20Records%20may%20not%20have%20a%20well%20defined%20schema%20depending%20on%20the%20source.%20When%20enabled%2C%20the%20format%20must%20be%20one%20of%20%E2%80%98avro%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98json%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98csv%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98tsv%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98delimited%E2%80%99.) Avro, JSON, and CSV file formats.
- Output Schema [is required](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/464945223/Google+Cloud+Storage+Multi+File+Sink#:%7E:text=found%20here.-,Output%20Schema,-Yes) for Avro, Parquet, and ORC schema. So, this might be a union schema of all tables or each schema referenced by the table name.
- Both cases are not manageable as you mentioned, it would be hell for the developer.

Additionally, this is already an issue I noticed on the plugin's page; https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/PLUGIN-1139

I would offer you one of the below flows/approaches to do what you want here:

- If Data Fusion is a must; then you can use the [PySpark or Spark plugins](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/plugins?hl=en#section-52:%7E:text=Storage%20location%20(stage).-,Spark,-Plugins%20for%20Spark) in Data Fusion and run one of the ready templates to extract data [from MySQL to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/templates/jdbc-to-storage).
- If data fusion is optional and you are already using Cloud Composer, you can still use the above-mentioned template with a serverless Dataproc or a Dataproc cluster that you create for this job and shut it down. This would save you a ton in the long run as you won't pay for Data Fusion and would just pay for Cloud Composer (which you already have) and Dataproc (which you were already going to pay for even when using Data Fusion) with the ability to shut it down.